# How to set up partitioning in Athena for application load balancer logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, partition

We have application load balancer logs in s3 that we query with Athena. We'd like to add partitions for year, month, date.

I'm following official [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html) which redirects to [github page](https://github.com/buzzsurfr/athena-add-partition) for adding partitions to table.

I've followed the guide but when ever I create table that has partitions either no records are returned or they are empty.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS alb_logs (  
  type string,  
  time string,  
  elb string,  
  client_ip string,  
  client_port int,  
  target_ip string,  
  target_port int,  
  request_processing_time double,  
  target_processing_time double,  
  response_processing_time double,  
  elb_status_code string,  
  target_status_code string,  
  received_bytes bigint,  
  sent_bytes bigint,  
  request_verb string,  
  request_url string,  
  request_proto string,
  user_agent string,  
  ssl_cipher string,  
  ssl_protocol string,  
  target_group_arn string,  
  trace_id string,  
  domain_name string,  
  chosen_cert_arn string,
  matched_rule_priority string,  
  request_creation_time string,
  actions_executed string,
  redirect_url string,
  error_reason string
)
PARTITIONED BY(year string, month string, day string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
'serialization.format' = '1',
'input.regex' =
'([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([-.0-9]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\"' )
LOCATION 's3://{LOG_BUCKET}/AWSLogs/{AWS_account_ID}/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-1/';
```

(we don't use prefix in our logs)

If I remove the `PARTITIONED BY(year string, month string, day string)` part then I have proper un-partitioned table created that I can query data from.

When I add the partition part then I get 0 records returned. Reading further as I understand I need to add those partitions. From that github page

> This template creates a Lambda function to add the partition and a CloudWatch Scheduled Event. Logs are sent from the Load Balancer into a S3 bucket. Daily, the CloudWatch Scheduled Event will invoke the Lambda function to add a partition to the Athena table.

But to be honest I'm not completely understanding this part. However I went ahead and deployed the provided [CloudFormation template](https://s3.amazonaws.com/athena-add-partition-us-east-1/template.json) with proper parameters. Now I do get records returned however for simple select all query

```
select * from alb_logs where year = '2020' and month "12" limit 100
```

all the fields are empty except the partition keys `year`, `month` and `day` (they weren't without `partition` part in `create table` command which to me indicates that regex isn't the problem)

Any help understanding what I'm doing wrong and how to properly set this up will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with partitions. It is probably a character scape issue. Probably a new line on the end of your **input.regex** on your table definition or something. Check my working example on a cloudformation yml file for a table setted for load balancer logging:

```
AlbAthenaTable:
    Type: AWS::Glue::Table
    Properties:
      CatalogId: !Ref AWS::AccountId
      DatabaseName: !Ref AthenaDataBase
      TableInput:
        Name: 
          !Join 
            - '_'
            - !Split 
                - '-'
                - !Sub ${AWS::StackName}_alb_table
        TableType: EXTERNAL_TABLE
        Parameters: { 
          "projection.day.type": "integer",
          "projection.day.range": "1,31",
          "projection.enabled": "true" }
        PartitionKeys:
        - Name: day
          Type: int
        StorageDescriptor:
          OutputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
          Columns:
            - Name: type
              Type: string
            - Name: time
              Type: string
            - Name: elb
              Type: string
            - Name: client_ip
              Type: string
            - Name: client_port
              Type: int
            - Name: target_ip
              Type: string
            - Name: target_port
              Type: int
            - Name: request_processing_time
              Type: double
            - Name: target_processing_time
              Type: double
            - Name: response_processing_time
              Type: double
            - Name: elb_status_code
              Type: string
            - Name: target_status_code
              Type: string
            - Name: received_bytes
              Type: bigint
            - Name: sent_bytes
              Type: bigint
            - Name: request_verb
              Type: string
            - Name: request_url
              Type: string
            - Name: request_proto
              Type: string
            - Name: user_agent
              Type: string
            - Name: ssl_cipher
              Type: string
            - Name: ssl_protocol
              Type: string 
            - Name: target_group_arn
              Type: string 
            - Name: trace_id 
              Type: string 
            - Name: domain_name
              Type: string 
            - Name: chosen_cert_arn 
              Type: string 
            - Name: matched_rule_priority
              Type: string
            - Name: request_creation_time 
              Type: string
            - Name: actions_executed  
              Type: string
            - Name: redirect_url  
              Type: string
            - Name: lambda_error_reason
              Type: string
            - Name: target_port_list
              Type: string
            - Name: target_status_code_list
              Type: string
            - Name: classification
              Type: string
            - Name: classification_reason
              Type: string
          InputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
          Location: 
            !Sub s3://${LoggingBucket}/${Prefix}/
          SerdeInfo:
            Parameters:
                serialization.format: 1
                input.regex: >-
                  ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)" "([^"]*)" ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)" ([-.0-9]*) ([^ ]*) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)" "([^ ]*)" "([^s]+?)" "([^s]+)" "([^ ]*)" "([^ ]*)"
            SerializationLibrary: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe
```

you need to go to the aws glue datacatalog console and check your **input.regex** in the **SerderInfo** in your **table properties** and ensure that it's looks like:

```
"input.regex": "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([-.0-9]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^s]+?)\" \"([^s]+)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\""
```

instead of:

```
"input.regex": "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*):([0-9]*) ([^ ]*)[:-]([0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) ([-.0-9]*) (|[-0-9]*) (-|[-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) ([-0-9]*) \"([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (- |[^ ]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([A-Z0-9-]+) ([A-Za-z0-9.-]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" ([-.0-9]*) ([^ ]*) \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^s]+?)\" \"([^s]+)\" \"([^ ]*)\" \"([^ ]*)\"\n"
```

the important thing to note here is that you can't have a new line ( neither spaces or another characteres) in the end of your input.regex! If it is the case, you will get the error that you reported.

I recomend you to create a table just like the documentation example. after that, create yours and, if you get some issue, check for differences between their settings.

Documentation example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/application-load-balancer-logs.html

Another thing (a little off-topic but very usefull in your purpose) is that you can use the feature called **partitions-projection** to predict partitions on a table-definition level. If you use this feature, you don't need to manually add new partitions or using a scheduler with a lambda for it at all.

Check the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html#partition-projection-using

I use this feature in my template too, in this part:

```
...
 TableInput:
        ...
        Parameters: { 
          "projection.day.type": "integer",
          "projection.day.range": "1,31",
          "projection.enabled": "true" }
        PartitionKeys:
        - Name: day
          Type: int
        ....
```

in my case i just use an integer. But partitions prediction supports date type and another types too.

Another off-topic tip:

I know that partitions and all this process can be a little tricky, so here is an article that explains all this process very deeply and in a very clear way (it's talk about cloudfront, but the foundations are the same):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-amazon-cloudfront-access-logs-at-scale/

Here is a github repo related to the article above, it's very helpfull:

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-access-logs-queries